# SonarQube and Sonar runner installation in Jenkins

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I have installed SonarQube-4.3 and Jenkins in my machine. To integrate Sonar with Jenkins installed the SonarQube plugin.

Do I need to install Sonar-runner in my machine in order to trigger a analysis through Jenkins?

Comment: Improve phrasing and remove duplication

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need SonarQube installed and running on same/different machine.
also you require SonarQube plugin in Jenkins which will connect SonarQube for Storing results.

Sonar-runner will be analyzer which will run analysis on your codebase.
You need to install sonar-runner on your local machine and have to specify its path in Jenkins system configuration.

Please find below the screenshots for detail purpose.

[image][image]

Comment: Thank you for the solution .I have another question .Now my SonarQube and Jenkins are in different machine and I have installed sonar runner2.4 in my local machine .Now in Jenkins for setting SONAR_RUNNER_HOME should I give the path of my local machine ? If yes could you please explain how jenkins in different machine identifies the sonar runner in my local machine?

Comment: Jenkins and SonarRunner must be on the same machine. If you installed SonarRunner under "/usr/local/sonar-runner", then add this path to the configuration.